# attempting to run multiple scripts, have them all output to one file, and all use the same IP address

Tags: vbscript

I have a couple questions and am hoping this is the correct place.

basically what i want to do is to be able to remotely get info about a domain computer.

i have 3 seperate scripts that give me 1( IP configuration, comp name ... ), 2 ( installed software )  and 3 ( mapped drives ).

the first two ask for the IP/computer name and the 3rd i have to input that into the script... i would like to only have to input the IP address once and have it work for all 3

secondly i would like the output file that this info is put into to be named like the installed software script does and then just have the other two scripts add ( ammend ) to the already created output.

I am super new to vbs so any help would be awesome

SCRIPT 1 ( gets IP configuration )

```
dim strComputer 'for computer name or IP
dim colAdapters 'collection of adapters


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("output.txt", True)


strComputer = ""

'open a dialog box asking for the computer name/IP
do
strComputer = inputbox( "Please enter a computername/IP, or . for local computer", "Input" )
Loop until strComputer <> "" 'run until a name/IP is entered


Set objWMIService = GetObject ("winmgmts:" & "!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 'open the WMI service on the remote PC
Set colAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True") 

'go through the list of adapters and gather data
For Each objAdapter in colAdapters 


objFile.Writeline "Host name: " & objAdapter.DNSHostName 
objFile.Writeline "DNS domain: " & objAdapter.DNSDomain 
objFile.Writeline "DNS suffix search list: " & objAdapter.DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder 
objFile.Writeline "Description: " & objAdapter.Description 
objFile.Writeline "Physical address: " & objAdapter.MACAddress 
objFile.Writeline "DHCP enabled: " & objAdapter.DHCPEnabled 
If Not IsNull(objAdapter.IPAddress) Then 
For i = LBound(objAdapter.IPAddress) To UBound(objAdapter.IPAddress) 
objFile.Writeline "IP address: " & objAdapter.IPAddress(i) 
Next 
End If 
If Not IsNull(objAdapter.IPSubnet) Then 
For i = LBound(objAdapter.IPSubnet) To UBound(objAdapter.IPSubnet) 
objFile.Writeline "Subnet: " & objAdapter.IPSubnet(i) 
Next 
End If 
If Not IsNull(objAdapter.DefaultIPGateway) Then 
For i = LBound(objAdapter.DefaultIPGateway) To UBound(objAdapter.DefaultIPGateway) 
objFile.Writeline "Default gateway: " & objAdapter.DefaultIPGateway(i) 
Next 
End If 
objFile.Writeline "DHCP server: " & objAdapter.DHCPServer 
If Not IsNull(objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder) Then 
For i = LBound(objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder) To UBound(objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder) 
objFile.Writeline "DNS server: " & objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder(i) 
Next 
End If 
objFile.Writeline "Primary WINS server: " & objAdapter.WINSPrimaryServer 
objFile.Writeline "Secondary WINS server: " & objAdapter.WINSSecondaryServer 
objFile.Writeline "Lease obtained: " & objAdapter.DHCPLeaseObtained 
objFile.Writeline "Lease expires: " & objAdapter.DHCPLeaseExpires 
Next
```

SCRIPT 2 ( gets installed software )

```
Option Explicit

Dim sTitle
sTitle = "InstalledPrograms.vbs by Bill James"
Dim StrComputer
strComputer = InputBox("Enter I.P. or name of computer to check for " & _
                       "installed software (leave blank to check " & _
                       "local system)." & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Remote " & _
                       "checking only from NT type OS to NT type OS " & _
                       "with same Admin level UID & PW", sTitle)
If IsEmpty(strComputer) Then WScript.Quit
strComputer = Trim(strComputer)
If strComputer = "" Then strComputer = "."

'Wscript.Echo GetAddRemove(strComputer)

Dim sCompName : sCompName = GetProbedID(StrComputer)

Dim sFileName
sFileName = sCompName & "_" & GetDTFileName() & "_Software.txt"

Dim s : s = GetAddRemove(strComputer)

If WriteFile(s, sFileName) Then
  'optional prompt for display
  If MsgBox("Finished processing.  Results saved to " & sFileName & _
            vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Do you want to view the results now?", _
            4 + 32, sTitle) = 6 Then
    WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run sFileName, 9
  End If
End If

Function GetAddRemove(sComp)
  'Function credit to Torgeir Bakken
  Dim cnt, oReg, sBaseKey, iRC, aSubKeys
  Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
              sComp & "/root/default:StdRegProv")
  sBaseKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
  iRC = oReg.EnumKey(HKLM, sBaseKey, aSubKeys)

  Dim sKey, sValue, sTmp, sVersion, sDateValue, sYr, sMth, sDay

  For Each sKey In aSubKeys
    iRC = oReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, "DisplayName", sValue)
    If iRC <> 0 Then
      oReg.GetStringValue HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, "QuietDisplayName", sValue
    End If
    If sValue <> "" Then
      iRC = oReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, _
                                "DisplayVersion", sVersion)
      If sVersion <> "" Then
        sValue = sValue & vbTab & "Ver: " & sVersion
      Else
        sValue = sValue & vbTab 
      End If
      iRC = oReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, sBaseKey & sKey, _
                                "InstallDate", sDateValue)
      If sDateValue <> "" Then
        sYr =  Left(sDateValue, 4)
        sMth = Mid(sDateValue, 5, 2)
        sDay = Right(sDateValue, 2)
        'some Registry entries have improper date format
        On Error Resume Next 
        sDateValue = DateSerial(sYr, sMth, sDay)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sdateValue <> "" Then
          sValue = sValue & vbTab & "Installed: " & sDateValue
        End If
      End If
      sTmp = sTmp & sValue & vbcrlf
    cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
  Next
  sTmp = BubbleSort(sTmp)
  GetAddRemove = "INSTALLED SOFTWARE (" & cnt & ") - " & sCompName & _
                 " - " & Now() & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & sTmp 
End Function

Function BubbleSort(sTmp)
  'cheapo bubble sort
  Dim aTmp, i, j, temp
  aTmp = Split(sTmp, vbcrlf)  
  For i = UBound(aTmp) - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For j = 0 to i - 1
      If LCase(aTmp(j)) > LCase(aTmp(j+1)) Then
        temp = aTmp(j + 1)
        aTmp(j + 1) = aTmp(j)
        aTmp(j) = temp
      End if
    Next
  Next
  BubbleSort = Join(aTmp, vbcrlf)
End Function

Function GetProbedID(sComp)
  Dim objWMIService, colItems, objItem
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComp & "\root\cimv2")
  Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select SystemName from " & _
                                         "Win32_NetworkAdapter",,48)
  For Each objItem in colItems
    GetProbedID = objItem.SystemName
  Next
End Function

Function GetDTFileName()
  dim sNow, sMth, sDay, sYr, sHr, sMin, sSec
  sNow = Now
  sMth = Right("0" & Month(sNow), 2)
  sDay = Right("0" & Day(sNow), 2)
  sYr = Right("00" & Year(sNow), 4)
  sHr = Right("0" & Hour(sNow), 2)
  sMin = Right("0" & Minute(sNow), 2)
  sSec = Right("0" & Second(sNow), 2)
  GetDTFileName = sMth & sDay & sYr & "_" & sHr & sMin & sSec
End Function

Function WriteFile(sData, sFileName)
  Dim fso, OutFile, bWrite
  bWrite = True
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sFileName, 2, True)
  'Possibly need a prompt to close the file and one recursion attempt.
  If Err = 70 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Could not write to file " & sFileName & ", results " & _
                 "not saved." & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "This is probably " & _
                 "because the file is already open."
    bWrite = False
  ElseIf Err Then
    WScript.Echo err & vbcrlf & err.description
    bWrite = False
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  If bWrite Then
    OutFile.WriteLine(sData)
    OutFile.Close
  End If
  Set fso = Nothing
  Set OutFile = Nothing
  WriteFile = bWrite
End Function
```

SCRIPT 3 ( gets mapped drives )

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("mappedoutput.txt", True)
' List Mapped Network Drives


On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_MappedLogicalDisk")

For Each objItem in colItems
    objFile.Writeline "Compressed: " & objItem.Compressed
    objFile.Writeline "Description: " & objItem.Description
    objFile.Writeline "Device ID: " & objItem.DeviceID
    objFile.Writeline "File System: " & objItem.FileSystem
    objFile.Writeline "Free Space: " & objItem.FreeSpace
    objFile.Writeline "Maximum Component Length: " & objItem.MaximumComponentLength
    objFile.Writeline "Name: " & objItem.Name
    objFile.Writeline "Provider Name: " & objItem.ProviderName
    objFile.Writeline "Session ID: " & objItem.SessionID
    objFile.Writeline "Size: " & objItem.Size
    objFile.Writeline "Supports Disk Quotas: " & objItem.SupportsDiskQuotas
    objFile.Writeline "Supports File-Based Compression: " & _
        objItem.SupportsFileBasedCompression
    objFile.Writeline "Volume Name: " & objItem.VolumeName
    objFile.Writeline "Volume Serial Number: " & objItem.VolumeSerialNumber
    objFile.Writeline
Next
```

Again thank you

Comment: i managed to create 4 batch files to automate it. i run this top one and each of the 1.bat, 2.bat are '"RemoteIP_Config - 2 v1.1.vbs"
exit'                                                           'start /wait 1.bat
start /wait 2.bat
start /wait 3.bat
exit'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you put all the three scripts as 1 single script? In that case, you will need to input the IP address only once.

Or else write another script which will ask for the IP address and call these scripts by using cscript and passing the IPaddress to them as a parameter. Try this code for that:

```
strcomputer = inputbox("Enter the IP address")
set obj1 = createobject("wscript.shell")
set obj2 = createobject("wscript.shell")
set obj3 = createobject("wscript.shell")
pgm1 = "cscript script1.vbs " & strcomputer
pgm2 = "cscript script2.vbs " & strcomputer
pgm3 = "cscript script3.vbs " & strcomputer
obj1.run pgm1,3,true
obj2.run pgm2,3,true
obj3.run pgm3,3,true
set obj1 = nothing
set obj2 = nothing
set obj3 = nothing
```

In above code, script1.vbs, script2.vbs, script3.vbs are your 3 scripts and you are executing them one by one using a new script.
In script1.vbs, add this line of code :

```
strcomputer = wscript.Arguments.item(0)
```

It will store the 1rst argument that you have passed from your new script to script1.vbs, into the variable 'strcomputer'(in your case, the IP address).
Similarly, in both script2.vbs and script3.vbs also, add the statement

```
strcomputer = wscript.Arguments.item(0)
```

Regarding your output file, I am not sure what you are asking for. Maybe this can help:

Use the below to write to a file (overwrites if data is already present):

```
Set fso1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject" )            
Set file1 = fso1.OpenTextFile("C:\New\textfile1.txt",2,true)
```

Use the below to add data or append to a file (does NOT overwrite):

```
Set fso1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject" )            
Set file1 = fso1.OpenTextFile("C:\New\textfile1.txt",8,true)
```

Use the below to read from a file:

```
Set fso1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject" )            
Set file1 = fso1.OpenTextFile("C:\New\textfile1.txt",1,true)
```

Comment: I would love to write it as one script but i am having issues getting that to work.  when i add them together it always runs one and then stops afterwards

Comment: and thank you so much for the response  after filling that in i have the mapped drives script running however the other two don't appear to be doing anything.  i took out all of the strcomputer code from all 3 scripts since that has been set in your script above.

Comment: ok now i have the getter and mapped rives working i had to take out the input box out of the getter script.  doing the same thing for the IPconfig script isn't working

Comment: i used a different script to get the IP info and added your additions and it worked perfectly  thank you.  now just to get it to save to 1 file :)

Comment: not yet :( i'm not sure if i should get the other two scripts to append to the software getter, ( i'm not sure how to drag the variable of the file name across to the next script ) or if i should just write in for them to go to one script in that first script that sets the strcomputer to the input box (your first reply)